# byte order mark in php files

Tags: php, csv, encoding, fopen, byte-order-mark

I want to open a csv file using php .
when I use English characters in this file anythings work well
but problem starts when I want to use Persians (one the write-to-left languages which is very similar to Arabic characters ) characters in my csv files .

all of Persian characters replace with '?' .

I know this problem is related to BOM but i don't know how to fix it .

Comment: What are you doing with the file exactly? This is about *handling encodings correctly*, not necessarily about the BOM.

Comment: You are right, you should find a way to encode your file to `UTF-8 without BOM`

Comment: Use .xls file this will more preferable.

Comment: I wrote some codes like this :
$file2 = fopen('book2.csv','r');

 while($data = fgetcsv($file2,1000,','))
 {
  foreach($data as $val)
   echo $val.' | ';
  echo '<br />'; 
 }

Comment: What encoding is the CSV file in? If you can't answer that, see [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: @AdvaitAmin
unfortunetly not.
it wasn't helpful .
:-(